# Fixed centered sticky footer can't position in center.. Ideas please

Tags: html, css

I have a 600px wide footer graphic that I want to be positioned in the center of the page. I currently have it fixed at the bottom of the browser, which is what I want - I want the content to scroll from underneath the footer, if you know what I mean.
With the fixed value my footer hangs on the left. With a value of relative, its centered, but stuck to the bottom of the page, and I end up having a load of blank white space to scroll down until I see the footer. Infact, removing the whole position: property has the same effect as the relative value.

How can I fix this?

I attempted ideas here - [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally) but none of them worked =[

CSS

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
margin-top: -110px; 
height: 110px;
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
clear:both;
bottom: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
html, body, and other div relative {
   width: 100%;
}


#footer {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -110px; 
    height: 110px;
    width: 600px;
    clear:both;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px; /* half size of footer */
}
```

Comment: I didn't add the width 100% bit at the top as it caused havoc with the rest of my page, but the footer stuff worked a treat.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="footerWrap">
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.footerWrap {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
.footer {
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:110px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/7qrhm/)

hope this help